# Invoking a static method with java reflection library

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to invoke the following static method through the java reflection library.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ah
{
  static void a()
  {
    try
    {
      Client.dU = 10;
      Client.dV = 0;
      Client.dX = true;
      cp.d = 32;
      cp.a(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
      Client.iq = Client.E();
      Client.ir = w.a();
      Client.is = 2019030189;
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException localUnknownHostException) {}
  }
}
```

My current code is as follows

```
public void invokeInit() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class<?> initClass = loader.loadClass("ah");
        Method initMethod = initClass.getDeclaredMethod("a", null);
        initMethod.invoke(null, new Object[] {});
    }
```

It gives me the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.baiocchi.client.reflection.Game can not access a member of class ah with modifiers "static"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:296)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:288)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at org.baiocchi.client.reflection.Game.invokeInit(Game.java:28)
    at org.baiocchi.client.reflection.Game.getApplet(Game.java:33)
    at org.baiocchi.client.Engine.start(Engine.java:21)
    at org.baiocchi.client.Booter.main(Booter.java:6)
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Your `invokeInit` is in the same package as your `ah` class?

Comment: no. The init() method is running on a separate program. I am trying to invoke it through my program using the invokeInit() method. @NeerajJain

Comment: @Bautista As Neeraj Jain suggested, either put them in same package or modify the method a to a public method

Comment: I cannot put them in the same package. How could i modify the method into being public? @Gearon

Comment: Err, put `public` in front of it? This is pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
>   org.baiocchi.client.reflection.Game can not access a member of class
>   ah with modifiers "static"

`IllegalAccessException` is thrown if you want to invoke a private or otherwise inaccessible method (generally a `package private` method while you don't invoke it from the package of the class).

You can invoke  `public void setAccessible(boolean flag)` on the `Method` object to remove this constraint :

```
initMethod.setAccessible(true);
```

> Set the accessible flag for this object to the indicated boolean
>   value. A value of true indicates that the reflected object should
>   suppress Java language access checking when it is used. A value of
>   false indicates that the reflected object should enforce Java language
>   access checks.

Comment: It should not. Which error ? `initMethod.setAccessible(true);` should be invoked before `initMethod.invoke(null, new Object[] {});`.
`